# WPF как правильно создавать MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я пытаюсь худо-бедно реализоввывать паттерн MVVM. При создании MenuItem возникли впросы по поводу привязки данных. 
Сейчас у меня в Model такая картина:

```
var menuCopyCutPasteDelete = new MenuItem[]
{
    new MenuItem(){Header = "Копировать"},
    new MenuItem(){Header = "Вырезать"},
    new MenuItem(){Header = "Вставить"},
    new MenuItem(){Header = "Удалить"},
};
var commands = new Model.Command[]
{
    new Model.Command(Model.FileBrowserManagers.Copy),
    new Model.Command(Model.FileBrowserManagers.Transfer),
    new Model.Command(Model.FileBrowserManagers.PasteAsync),
    new Model.Command(Model.FileBrowserManagers.Delete),
};
for (int i = 0; i < menuCopyCutPasteDelete.Length; i++)
{
    int a = i;
    menuCopyCutPasteDelete[a].Click += (sender,e) => commands[a].Execute(sender);
}
```

Выглядит очень ужасно. Возможно я должен создавать MenuItem элементы в xaml и биндить к ним ивенты? Или есть другой вариант? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Меню это чисто вьюшная сущность, ни VM, ни модель уж тем более ничего о нем и знать не должны. Выставляйте в VM команды, а в XAML описывайте меню и привязывайте команды к пунктам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описываете в xaml меню:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Файл">
        <MenuItem Header="Копировать" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Вырезать"   Command="{Binding CutCommand}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Вставить"   Command="{Binding PasteCommand}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Удалить"    Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

В VM создаете команды(реализации ICommand есть такие как DelegateCommand, RelayCommand, можно найти в интернете):

```
public class MainVM : BaseVM
{
    public ICommand CopyCommand   { get; }
    public ICommand CutCommand    { get; }
    public ICommand PasteCommand  { get; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

в WPF есть стандартные уже реализованные команды попробуй их:

```
<MenuItem Header="Edit">
    <MenuItem Command ="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
    <MenuItem Command ="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/> 
    <MenuItem Command ="ApplicationCommands.Paste"/>
    <MenuItem Command ="ApplicationCommands.Delete"/> 
</MenuItem>
```

Эти команды даже сами назначят горячее клавиши и Header для MenuItem

Comment: Только нужно не забыть о `RegisterCommandBinding`.